# Facebook FQL API - APIError: 1: An unknown error occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-fql

I have a FQL query that given a page_id to find photo location_post by your facebook friends.

```
rest_client.fql_query("SELECT id, page_id, author_uid, coords, type, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND type = 'photo' AND page_id = 212068492162618")
```

However, it returned APIError: 1: An unknown error occurred

> Koala::Facebook::APIError: 1: An unknown error occurred   from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/koala-1.0.0/lib/koala/rest_api.rb:16:in
>   `rest_call'   from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/koala-1.0.0/lib/koala.rb:55:in`api'
>     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/koala-1.0.0/lib/koala/rest_api.rb:13:in
>   `rest_call'   from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/koala-1.0.0/lib/koala/rest_api.rb:7:in`
>   fql_query'   from (irb):51   from :0

if I get rid of either **author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())**, as following or **page_id = 212068492162618**, then it works

```
rest_client.fql_query("SELECT id, page_id, author_uid, coords, type, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE AND type = 'photo' AND page_id = 212068492162618 LIMIT 500")
```

Any idea why this may happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the query you are looking to try is

SELECT id, page_id, author_uid, coords, type, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE type = 'photo' AND page_id = 212068492162618"

This will automatically expand to all your friends as given in the example on 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/